# lilypond errors

Tags: notation

Can someone tells me what wrong with my code?

```
    **\version "2.22.1"

% this is my first score
\language "english"
\header {
   title = "Aint Necessarily So"
   %composer = " "
   subtitle = "Bronski Beat"
} %/ end header

%%%%%%%%% Function Declarations
fdo = #(define-music-function () () 
 #{
    \pad
   _\markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four five six))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ()))
}}} 
#})

fre = #(define-music-function () ()
#{
    \pad
   _\markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four five))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ()))
   } } }
#})


fmi = #(define-music-function () ()
#{
    \pad
   _\markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three five))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ()))
   } } }
#})

ffa = #(define-music-function () ()
#{
    \pad
   _\markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two five))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ()))
   } } }
#})

fsol = #(define-music-function () ()
#{
    \pad
   _\markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (two five))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ()))
   } } }
#})

fla = #(define-music-function () ()
#{
    \pad
   _\markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four five))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ()))
   } } }
#})

fsi = #(define-music-function () ()
#{
   \pad
   _\markup 
    \center-column 
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ()))
   } 
#})



pad = \once \override TextScript.padding = #4 


\relative {
  \key g \minor 
  \numericTimeSignature
  \time 4/4
  \fdo g'8
  \fre d'4  \fre d8  \fsol g4, \fdo c4 \fdo c4 \fsol g4 
  \fsi b2.
}**
```

please, see log errors and warnings - how is the easy to prevent them?

Starting lilypond-windows.exe 2.22.1 [Aint-Necessarily-So.ly]...
Processing `C:/Users/TOMMY_~1/AppData/Local/Temp/frescobaldi-ro92knuj/tmpi_my1xgx/Aint-Necessarily-So.ly'
Parsing...
C:/Users/TOMMY_~1/AppData/Local/Temp/frescobaldi-ro92knuj/tmpi_my1xgx/Aint-Necessarily-So.ly:106:3: warning: Unattached TextScriptEvent

\fdo g'8

C:/Users/TOMMY_~1/AppData/Local/Temp/frescobaldi-ro92knuj/tmpi_my1xgx/Aint-Necessarily-So.ly:107:3: warning: Unattached TextScriptEvent

\fre d'4  \fre d8  \fsol g4, \fdo c4 \fdo c4 \fsol g4

C:/Users/TOMMY_~1/AppData/Local/Temp/frescobaldi-ro92knuj/tmpi_my1xgx/Aint-Necessarily-So.ly:107:13: warning: Unattached TextScriptEvent
\fre d'4
\fre d8  \fsol g4, \fdo c4 \fdo c4 \fsol g4

C:/Users/TOMMY_~1/AppData/Local/Temp/frescobaldi-ro92knuj/tmpi_my1xgx/Aint-Necessarily-So.ly:107:22: warning: Unattached TextScriptEvent
\fre d'4  \fre d8
\fsol g4, \fdo c4 \fdo c4 \fsol g4

C:/Users/TOMMY_~1/AppData/Local/Temp/frescobaldi-ro92knuj/tmpi_my1xgx/Aint-Necessarily-So.ly:107:30: error: octave marks must precede duration
\fre d'4  \fre d8  \fsol g4
, \fdo c4 \fdo c4 \fsol g4

C:/Users/TOMMY_~1/AppData/Local/Temp/frescobaldi-ro92knuj/tmpi_my1xgx/Aint-Necessarily-So.ly:107:32: warning: Unattached TextScriptEvent
\fre d'4  \fre d8  \fsol g4,
\fdo c4 \fdo c4 \fsol g4

C:/Users/TOMMY_~1/AppData/Local/Temp/frescobaldi-ro92knuj/tmpi_my1xgx/Aint-Necessarily-So.ly:107:40: warning: Unattached TextScriptEvent
\fre d'4  \fre d8  \fsol g4, \fdo c4
\fdo c4 \fsol g4

C:/Users/TOMMY_~1/AppData/Local/Temp/frescobaldi-ro92knuj/tmpi_my1xgx/Aint-Necessarily-So.ly:107:48: warning: Unattached TextScriptEvent
\fre d'4  \fre d8  \fsol g4, \fdo c4 \fdo c4
\fsol g4

C:/Users/TOMMY_~1/AppData/Local/Temp/frescobaldi-ro92knuj/tmpi_my1xgx/Aint-Necessarily-So.ly:108:3: warning: Unattached TextScriptEvent

\fsi b2.

Interpreting music...
Preprocessing graphical objects...
Finding the ideal number of pages...
Fitting music on 1 page...
Drawing systems...
Converting to `Aint-Necessarily-So.pdf'...
fatal error: failed files: "C:\Users\TOMMY_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\frescobaldi-ro92knuj\tmpi_my1xgx\Aint-Necessarily-So.ly"
Exited with return code 1.

well, as you suggested it works... no more errors.
I did remove the comma and re-write a bit different my code as:

```
fsi = #(define-music-function () ()
```

#{
\pad
_\markup
\center-column
\override #'(size . 0.7) {
\woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four))
(lh . ())
(rh . ()))
}
#})

pad = \once \override TextScript.padding = #4

\relative **c''** {
\key g \minor
\numericTimeSignature
\time 4/4
\fdo g8
**\fre d4  \fre d8  \fsol g4 \fdo c4 \fdo c4 \fsol g4**
\fsi b2.
}

I tried to eliminate warnings as it suggested above but still have them:

C:/Users/TOMMY_~1/AppData/Local/Temp/frescobaldi-ro92knuj/tmpi_my1xgx/Aint-Necessarily-So.ly:107:46: warning: Unattached TextScriptEvent
\fre d4  \fre d8  \fsol g4 \fdo c4 \fdo c4
\fsol g4

C:/Users/TOMMY_~1/AppData/Local/Temp/frescobaldi-ro92knuj/tmpi_my1xgx/Aint-Necessarily-So.ly:108:3: warning: Unattached TextScriptEvent

\fsi b2.

Is there a way to eliminate them?

Thanks,
Tommy Tsalisher

Comment: All over stack overflow, it is appreciated if not expected, that an attempt is made to arrive at a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error `"error: octave marks must precede duration \fre d'4 \fre d8 \fsol g4 , \fdo c4 \fdo c4 \fsol g4"` is because of the comma following `\fsol g4`.

\fre d'4 \fre d8 **\fsol g4 ,** \fdo c4 \fdo c4 \fsol g4

---

The remaining warnings can be eliminated by eliminating the scheme functions and instead defining lilypond variables such as:

```
fdo = \pad
      \markup {
      \center-column {
      \override #'(size . 0.7) {
      \woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four five six))
                                    (lh . ())
                                    (rh . ()))}}}
```

This is based on [an email thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/lilypond-user@gnu.org/msg144673.html) in which the same warning was occurring. In particular, see [Robin Bannister's enail of Mon, 17 May 2021 03:16:21 -0700](https://www.mail-archive.com/lilypond-user@gnu.org/msg144673.html).

> You have two cases of the 'Unattached TextScriptEvent' warning.
> This sort of thing happens when LilyPond can't find the corresponding note. It may discard the TextScriptEvent, but it usually lets it drift along and settle onto the following note.
> warning: Unattached TextScriptEvent

> orange = {
> ^

> In the first cases your **outer curly brackets are isolating the TextScriptEvent from the surroundings**. Get rid of them. (emphasis mine)

Comment: and what about these warnings: C:/Users/TOMMY_~1/AppData/Local/Temp/frescobaldi-ro92knuj/tmpi_my1xgx/Aint-Necessarily-So.ly:107:46: warning: Unattached TextScriptEvent
  \fre d4  \fre d8  \fsol g4 \fdo c4 \fdo c4 
                                             \fsol g4 

C:/Users/TOMMY_~1/AppData/Local/Temp/frescobaldi-ro92knuj/tmpi_my1xgx/Aint-Necessarily-So.ly:108:3: warning: Unattached TextScriptEvent
  
  \fsi b2.

Comment: I can not figure why they pop up...

Comment: @Tommy_tsa Just posted an answer, which I've tested.